# Display shipping charges above ADD TO CART button

Tags: shipping, product-view

visit this [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

search for "check" using CTRL + F, you can see :

[image]

enter "560043" as zip code & click on "check" button , you can see :

"RS 50 " , this is shipping charge. Instead of displaying "Rs 50 " here,

I want to display above "ADD TO CART" button as Selling Price + Rs 50 Delivery

It should prefix with "Selling Price +" & suffix with "Delivery" as [link2](http://test.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html)

we are using following code for display shipping charges.

**Edit**

so what i did is I placed complete code in view.phtml file. but now we are getting only error message when we click on " check" button, its not calculating shipping charges.

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/result.phtml

<?php if ($this->getResult()):?>
        <dl>
            <?php foreach ($this->getResult() as $code => $_rates): ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                        <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                           <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                                <?php echo $_rate->getErrorMessage() ?>
                           <?php else: ?>
                                <?php 
                            //  echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() 
                                ?>
                                <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                                <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
                                <?php echo $_excl; ?>
                                <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                                    (<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                                <?php endif; ?>
                           <?php endif ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php //echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getResult(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

view.phtml : http://pastebin.com/EWnACrsT // 30000 charactars allowed.

Comment: Use this code above Your Add to cart code

Comment: i will try  calling this phtml code.

Comment: i used this code in static block: 

`{{block type="core/template" name="charges" template="webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/form.phtml"}}`


i am using this code : `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('charges')->toHtml(); 
?> ` in view.phtml file

but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents: why don't you consider moving the HTML block via JavaScript?

It's easier, can be easily toggled and gives you more control without touching original templates.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you please update the answer with code.

Comment: Sorry I'm not such a JavaScript expert. What's more it depends on which library you want to use (prototype, jquery). The idea is that of adding some code to the check callback to identify the desired block and move it through the DOM.